# Minimize embedded youtube video to just listed to sound

Tags: youtube

Is it possible to embed a youtube video and hide video display and just show the player controls? That would be sufficient for playing songs.

(I know, it would be a waste of bandwidth ;-) ...)

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but there are websites that allow you to put in the address of a YouTube video and extract the audio from the file.

Answer (score 1):

So far as I'm aware this isn't possible in a *useful* way.

For a single video you could set the width and height to 1px and enable autoplay, but I don't know how far that would get you.

I doubt you can change the window height to just show the scrubber bar as youtube's content scales automatically with the size.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/) to embed the youtube videos, then you can customise it in many ways, including only showing the controls.

See [embedding an audio file](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/15993/playing-an-audio-file) in the JW player documentation.

Note that this does not work for youtube videos with adverts.